# Are these group presentations trivial?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-topology

I just got these presentations of groups:

$\langle a,b\mid aba^{-1}b^{-1}\rangle$

$\langle a,b\mid aba^{-1}b^{-2},bab^{-1}a^{-2}\rangle$

$\langle a,b\mid abab^{-1}\rangle $

Are any of them trivial? How do you prove it?

Comment: A group given by a presentation with more generators than relators *must* be infinite, never mind trivial!

Comment: For the second group, I will mention http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66573/a-particular-two-variable-system-in-a-group/66632#66632

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first and last group, try finding a homomorphism from your group $G$ to an abelian group.  If you can find an onto map $G \to A$ where $A$ is nontrivial, then $G$ is non-trivial.  If you have a group $G=\langle a,b\mid r\rangle$ and you decide you want to map $G\to A$ by $a\mapsto x$ and $b \mapsto y$, you get a homomorphism if and only if the result of substituting $x$ for $a$ and $y$ for $b$ in $r$ is trivial.

For the middle one, you've got $aba^{-1}=b^2$ and $bab^{-1}=a^2$ (1).  Rewriting the first one gives $ab (ba^{-1}b^{-1}) = b$.  Work out $ba^{-1}b^{-1}$ from (1) and substitute...

Comment: thanks but are there any rules of rewriting like you did?

Comment: No.  (Actually it's a theorem that the answer is no: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_problem_for_groups - there's no general algorithm that will decide whether or not a given word is the identity).  So every time you can do it, it's a little victory against the universe.

Answer (score 4):

Standard techniques that work with the kinds of groups you've given is to compute the abelianization of the group.  At least one of your groups is abelian - so you can describe it using the classification of finitely-generated abelian groups.

Sometimes the abelianization gives you further ideas, like trying to prove your group is a semi-direct product.  There's something called the Reidemeister-Schreir technique that will help you with this.  Your 3rd group appears to be a semi-direct product.

Comment: I assume you actually know the third group very well; it's the fundamental group of the Klein bottle.

Comment: @user641: What you assume is irrelevant to this forum.  This isn't a forum for anonymous users to solve people's homework problems.