# If $a^{-1} b^2 a=b^3$ and $b^{-1}a^2 b=a^3$ with $a,b\in G$, $G$ a group, then $a=b=1$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I had this problem.

> Let $G$ be a group and $a,b\in G$ such that $a^{-1} b^2 a=b^3$ and $b^{-1}a^2 b=a^3$. Prove that $a=b=1$.

Somehow I solved it, but it was a bit tedious (for example in some place I got to something like $b^3 =a^{-3}b^{-1}a^2a^{-3}b^{-1}a^2a^{-3}b^{-1}a^2=a^{-3}b^{-1}a^{-1}b^{-1}a^{-1}b^{-1}a^{2}$). I first proved that $b=a^{-2}ba^3$ (It's also true that $b=a^2ba^{-3}$) and then (Details not included) that $b^3=ab^6a^3$. Then (Details not included) that $b^3 a^3=a^{-1}b$, then $b^{-1}=a^4$ and from that $a^2=a^3$, from which $a=e$ (There are a lot of lines covering these details but there may be a mistake in these lines). It's the same to get $b=e$.

So, is there any shorter, or less tedious way to prove it?

Answer (score 0):

This follow from Theorem $1$ and Corollary $3$ of the article [Some presentations of the trivial group](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjz-43fvdvLAhVLEJoKHV6-CY8QFggbMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ms.unimelb.edu.au%2F~cfm%2Fpapers%2Fpaperpdfs%2Fcfmpes990426.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEObhbJ9YfKeHXq4Qt7mVk-pd1Kew&sig2=yTlte175LJOB3Cm25BP9qg&bvm=bv.117868183,d.bGs) by Miller and Schupp, because $a^{-1}b^na=b^{n+1}$  and $a=w=b^{-1}a^2ba^{-2}$ has exponent sum $0$ in $a$.

Edit: In addition, I found the same question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66573/a-particular-two-variable-system-in-a-group/66632#66632).