# For $x,y$ in G, prove that $x = y =e$ if $xy^2=y^3x $ and $yx^2=x^3y$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

For $x,y$ in G, prove that $x = y =e$ if $xy^2=y^3x $ and $yx^2=x^3y$  where $e$ is the identity element in G.

I have filled pages trying to solve but unable to reach the solution. 
Also, Is there any general method to approach such questions?

Comment: There is no general method. The general problem is called the _word problem_ (for groups), and it is considered hard.

Comment: Does that mean I have to mug up approach for these questions? Most of the time I end up with the given equations when trying to solve.

Comment: Is $G$ a finite group?

Comment: It's not given as such.

Comment: An essential [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/66573/11619). Mind you, I like 1Enigma1's solution over mine (Steve D's is better than mine). Using the fact that conjugates have the same order saves a number of steps. Therefore I won't cast the first vote to close as a dupe.

Comment: It is not true  that there is no general method to approach such problems. But there is no method that is guaranteed to deliver the answer within any specified time. The methods, such as coset enumeration, are algorithmic, and best carried out using computer software.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I am sorry, I should have taken the question with your answer first. Now there is a chain with 4 duplicates, ending with your answer.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Nothing to worry about there. My answer is A) incomplete, B) not sleekest. So I'm not worried about its exact place in the food chain. I'm sure you judged it well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $xy^2=y^3x$ say  $(1)$ and  $yx^2=x^3y$ say  $(2)$

From the relation $(1)$, we have $xy^2x^{−1}=y^3$ say $(3)$.

Computing the power of $n$ of this equality yields that
$xy^{2n}x^{−1}=y^{3n}$ for any $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

In particular, we have $xy^4x^{−1}=y^6$ and $xy^6x^{−1}=y^9$..
Substituting the former into the latter, we obtain
$x^2y^4x^{−2}=y^9,$ say $(4)$

Cubing both sides gives $x^2y^{12}x^{−2}=y^{27}$.

Using the relation $(3)$ with $n=4$, we have $xy^8x^{−1}=y^{12}$
Substituting this into equality $(4)$ yields $x^3y^8x^{−1}=y^{27}$

Now we have
$$y^{27}=x^3y^8x^{−3}=(x^3y)y^8(y^{−1}x^{−3})=yx^2y^8x^{−2}y^{−1}.$$

Squaring the relation $(4)$, we have $x^2y^8x^{−2}=y^{18}$.
Substituting this into the previous, we obtain $y^{27}=y^{18}$, and hence
$$y^9=e$$
Note that as we have $xy^2x^{−1}=y^3$, the elements $y^2,y^3$ are conjugate to each other.
Thus, the orders must be the same. This observation together with $y^9=e$ imply $y=e$.

It follows from the relation $(2)$ that $x=e$ as well.

Comment: Can I ask what was the background idea(s) you had to find this!?!