# Prove a group is equal to its commutator subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

Let $G$ be the group generated by $a,b$ satisfying the relations $ba^3=a^2b, ab^2=b^3a$.

How can I prove $G = [G,G]$ which is the commutator group of $G$?

Comment: G is the trivial group, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66573/a-particular-two-variable-system-in-a-group?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: It's a lot easier to prove that $G = [G,G]$ than it is to prove that $G$ is trivail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From $ab^2=b^3a$ we have: $$
\begin{align}
[a,b^2]&=ab^2a^{-1}b^{-2}\\
&=b^3aa^{-1}b^{-2}\\
&=b
\end{align}$$ so $b\in[G,G]$.

Also, from $ba^3=a^2b$ we have: $$\begin{align}
[b^{-1},a^2]&=b^{-1}a^2ba^{-2} \\
&=b^{-1}ba^3a^{-2} \\
&=a
\end{align}$$ so $a\in[G,G]$.

Thus, both $a,b\in [G,G]$, which implies $G=[G,G]$.