# What is the group $G=\langle a,b \mid ab^2=b^3a,ba^3=a^2b\rangle $

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, combinatorial-group-theory

I feel that $G$ is infinite, however I don't know how to deal with the relationship $ab^2=b^3a,ba^3=a^2b$

Comment: This is a well-known example of a presentation of the trivial group. This has been asked many times before.

Comment: The center of the cluster seems to be https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66573/a-particular-two-variable-system-in-a-group

Comment: I got that, thanks!